# Ajax wordpress single page

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I see thousands of posts that have to do with ajaxing wordpress but none of them actually show you how to implement the single page into it. What im trying to achieve is have the single.php page load into the same page when the permalink in the actual blog section is clicked. Any idea on how I can do this?

Thank you.

- Robert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

```
$('#result').load('/file/you/want/to/load.php');
```